# Display string data in message box

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Why is this not working with TJSONObject?

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  js : TJSONObject;
  isoDate1, isoDate2, data : string;
begin
  isoDate1 := '2018-01-02T10:00:00.000Z';
  isoDate2 := '2018-01-02T10:10:00.000Z';

  js := TJSONObject.Create;
  js.AddPair(TJsonPair.Create(isoDate1, 'TEST'));
  js.AddPair(TJsonPair.Create(isoDate2, 'TEST2'));

  outputdebugstring(pchar(js.ToString));

  if js.TryGetValue<string>(isoDate1, data) then begin
    ShowMessage(data);
  end else begin
    ShowMessage('data non trouvé pour ' + isoDate1);
  end;
end;
```

> output : Sortie de débogage: {"2018-01-02T10:00:00.000Z":"TEST","2018-01-02T10:10:00.000Z":"TEST2"} Processus Project1.exe (6232)

Expected Outcome:
The TryGetValue should put a string in data
ShowMessage should give me 'TEST' in a message box.

Outcome:
The ShowMessage give me 'data non trouvé pour 2018-01-02T10:00:00.000Z'.

Comment: What are you expecting? What is not working?

Comment: The TryGetValue should put a string in data and ShowMessage should give me 'TEST' in a message box?

Comment: So what does happen?

Comment: The ShowMessage give me 'data non trouvé pour 2018-01-02T10:00:00.000Z' which I thought definitely should be 'TEST'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the dot in your JSON path that you query with the [**TryGetValue**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.TryGetValue) method call. Dot char path parser ([**TJSONPathParser**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONPathParser)) interprets as key separator of pairs, whose value is about to be obtained. So, for example call like this:

```
if JSONObject.TryGetValue<string>('Foo.Bar', S) then
  DoSomething;
```

is a query for **The value** of an object like this:

```json
{"Foo": {"Bar": "The value"}}
```

not for **The value** with the key named this way:

```json
{"Foo.Bar": "The value"}
```

So in your case you were trying to query the value of the **2018-01-02T10:00:00** object's key **000Z**, which would require object like this:

```json
{"2018-01-02T10:00:00": {"000Z": "TEST"}}
```

This JSON path dot notation is hardcoded at this time (without possibility of escaping dot chars in the queried path), so the only way is giving up on that method at this moment, or losing dots from key names.

Comment: But why js.toString give me : {"2018-01-02T10:00:00.000Z":"TEST","2018-01-02T10:10:00.000Z":"TEST2"}, which is a validated JSON, also the dot is a part of ISO, I am not sure to remove it

Comment: Oddly, `js.GetValue(isoDate1).toString` worked but not `js.GetValue<string>(isoDate1)`

Comment: You have a valid JSON. The probem is that `TryGetValue` supports dot notation of paths and _thinks_ that you're querying value of an object that I've shown in this post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the dot in your key. It's used as a seperator.
Delphi interprets '2018-01-02T10:00:00' as an object which has '000Z' as a property.

I would sugguest to get the value like this:

```
var
...
  LJsonValue: TJSONValue;
begin
...

  LJsonValue := js.GetValue(isoDate1);
  if Assigned(LJsonValue) then
    ShowMessage(LJsonValue.Value);

...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON path syntax in GetValue...

```
... MySt := JSONObject.GetValue<string>('["Foo"]["Bar"]') ...
```